# How to prove this big O identity

Tags: analytic-number-theory

This question was asked in my quiz (now over) and I was unable to solve it.

For $0<y<1$ , prove that $\log[(1-y) ^{-1}] = y + O(y^2)$.

I tried using expansion of $\frac{ 1} { 1-y} $ and trying to prove $\frac{ log ( 1+ y+ y^2+...) -y }{y^2}$  will always be less than a particular constant for all $y \geq a$, but unable to do so.

So, can you please help with this.

Apologies for the typo.

Comment: You mean $\log [(1-y)^{-1}]$? This would be equal to $-\log(1-y)$ from the exponent rule, right?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to consider $log(\frac{1}{1-y})$ and not $\frac{1}{log(1-y)}$? Writing $log(1-y)^{-1}$ could mean both.

Comment: Consider the Taylor series expansion 
$log(\frac{1}{1-y}) = y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} + ...$

Comment: What is $x$? You have to show it for $0<y<1$. A more precise statement would be for $0<y\leq 1-\delta<1$ with a fixed $\delta>0$, because there is no absolute constant for the whole of $0<y<1$.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon ya I meant that.

Comment: Indeed,  then , we must examine the quantity $\frac{-\log(1-y)-y}{y^2}$ and see how if it's bounded (at least in modulus) in $(0,1)$. We can do this by seeing if $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\log(1-y)-y}{y^2}$ exists, and if $\lim_{y \to 1}\frac{-\log(1-y)-y}{y^2}$ exists. The former exists and equals $\frac 12$ (L'Hospital twice should do the trick) while the latter is positive infinite (using L'Hospital with the $\limsup,\liminf$ variation twice). So you won't need a Taylor series to confirm that indeed the quotient is bounded in $[0,1-\delta]$ for any $1>\delta>0$, as mentioned earlier. Not at $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on other answers and comments, note first that the claim is false as $y$ approaches 1, since
$$
\lim_{y\to 1} \left[ \log((1-y)^{-1}) \right] = \infty.
$$
That is, the claim is false if $y$ is allowed to be arbitrarily close to 1. Thus we need a uniform bound on the possible values of $y$; i.e. we need to assume the slightly stronger statement that $y\leq 1-\delta$ for some fixed positive number $\delta$.

Now the result follows almost immediately from the Taylor series expansion of $-\log(1-y)$:
$$
-\log(1-y) = y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} + \cdots.
$$
The tail is bounded via
$$
\frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} + \cdots \leq y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + \cdots = \frac{y^2}{1-y},
$$
where we have summed the geometric series since $\left|y\right| < 1$. Then
$$
\frac{y^2}{1-y} \leq \frac{y^2}{1-(1-\delta)} = \frac{y^2}{\delta}.
$$
Therefore
$$
-\log(1-y) = y + O(y^2),
$$
where the constant implied in the $O$ notation depends on $\delta$ and may be taken to be $\frac{1}{\delta}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Considering natural logarithm

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right) = \ln\left(1+\frac{y}{1-y}\right)=\\
=\frac{y}{1-y}-\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^2\frac{1}{2}+ \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^3\frac{1}{3}-\cdots=\\
\text{Addition}\\
=y+\frac{y^2}{1-y} - \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^2\frac{1}{2}+ o(y^2)=y+O(y^2)$$

Comment: That then requires a second step turning each term into a series.  Wouldn't the Taylor series for $-\ln(1-y)$ be easier?

Comment: @Henry. Really I have in view $\frac{y}{1-y}-y=\frac{y^2}{1-y}$, not what you imagine/suggest. It's no need any other series as what left is big-$O$. "Easier" is subjective word and down vote correct answer only for own fantasy is now considering right?

Comment: @zkutch I'm trying to follow your answer , and $\ln(\frac{1}{1-y}) -y= (\frac{y}{1-y} -y ) - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{y}{1-y})^2 + ...$, now $(\frac{y}{1-y} -y ) = \frac{y^2}{1-y}$ so I'm left with $\frac{y^2}{1-y}  - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{y}{1-y})^2 + ...$, now this is $y^2 \times f(y)$ for some complicated looking $f$. We need $f$ to be bounded by a constant for $0<y<1$, and this is not immediately clear to me. Can you see if I'm making a mistake?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon. For what you called "complicated looking" $f$, you had calculate limit, in your comment above,  using L'Hospital twice, without any complication,  Unique, which I find little complicate is second times used L'Hospital - why you need it? - answer is clear after first step. Anyway, I wrote addition.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, but the $f$ I derived was from your power series : so it remained to me as one, and I don't know how to deal with a power series as $y \to 1$ (although as $y \to 0$ I am good of course). On the other hand, when I did L'Hospital I didn't have to deal with those coefficients. That's why I asked. Anyways, thank you for the elaboration and +1.